# Do I have to watch The Mechanic before watching Mechanic Resurrection?

Tags: the-mechanic, mechanic-resurrection

Now ***Mechanic Resurrection*** is going to be released tomorrow and I am planning to watch it, but I didn't see ***The Mechanic (2011)***.

So, do I need to watch The Mechanic before watching Mechanic Resurrection to understand the characters or any story element? Is there any plot links to the first movie?

Comment: I'm not always an advocate of the original, but The Mechanic (1972) is definitely worth watching if you like the genre.

Comment: Yes, you must.  The video signal in The Mechanic contains the eyeball coating that you need to protect them from melting from the video signal in Mechanic Resurrection.  Little known fact. Probably because I pulled it from my posterior.

Comment: The best advice would be not to watch Mechanic Resurrection at all. The first is a passable remake, Resurrection is awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, **you don't need to watch the first part** to fully understand the story, characters and themes of the second one.

All you need to know is that the main character is a hitman specialized on making his kills look like accidents and that he's out of business and believed to be dead. But as much is already conveyed right at the beginning of *Mechanic: Resurrection*. There are **no other story elements or characters from *The Mechanic* who make an appearance in the sequel**. There is some additional backstory and characters from Bishop's past life involved in the new film, but none of them are mentioned in the previous film.

All you need to know about this film is that Jason Statham plays a classic Jason Statham character and goes full Jason Statham on people. ;-)